# Azure TimerTrigger not firing when trying to output multiple events to event grid topic

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an azure timer function.

1. It works when I run it locally.
2. It works if I remove this code when running in Azure:

   [EventGrid(TopicEndpointUri = "EventGridUri", TopicKeySetting = "EventGridKey")] IAsyncCollector outputEvents
3. Otherwise it does not work. The timer never seems to go off and the function is not triggered.

The code is below. I have tried removing the for loop and everything else with the  idea that I might be getting a silent exception, but the function still does not execute. Any idea how to troubleshoot or what might be causing the issue?

```
  public static class TimeTest
    {
        [FunctionName("TimeTest")]        
        public static async Task Run(
            [TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
    [EventGrid(TopicEndpointUri = "EventGridUri", TopicKeySetting = "EventGridKey")] IAsyncCollector<EventGridEvent> outputEvents)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var myEvent = new EventGridEvent("message-id-" + i, "subject-name", "event-data", "event-type", DateTime.UtcNow, "1.0");
                await outputEvents.AddAsync(myEvent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble finding the exception, but was finally able to see it when I went to application insights for the entire functions app (as opposed to trying to see logs at the function level).

It said that my eventuri was incorrect. After taking a closer look I realized that I had not given my functions permission to the keyvault.